# Get Soundcloud full URL via API url

Tags: php, soundcloud

I have a Soundcloud API URL, example:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/392847234
```

And I want to get the full permalink URL, something like:

```
http://soundcloud.com/dengue/sets/nuevos-sonidos
```

What is the best way to get the permalink URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach your client ID to the tracks URL and fetch the json results. It will include a field 'permalink_url' that you can use. The ID in your example URL was not found, so I used this instead:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/32750851.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Results:

`{"kind":"track","id":32750851,"created_at":"2012/01/08 09:26:58 +0000","user_id":8839325,"duration":84850,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":2040912,"last_modified":"2013/02/28 16:26:36 +0000","sharing":"public","tag_list":"","permalink":"lagrimas-del-corazon","streamable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","downloadable":false,"purchase_url":null,"label_id":null,"purchase_title":null,"genre":"rap romantic","title":"Lagrimas del corazon","description":"“Lagrimas Del Corazon” \r\nLagrimas de amor  sobre mis mejillas \r\nPensando si mi corazon  Tendra  salida \r\nNo lo puedo ver  No se donde estara \r\nPero se que mi corazon  Siempre lo esperara \r\nNo puedo escuchar Lo que me esta diciendo \r\nPero se que su corazon  Siempre me estara oyendo \r\nPor que….” \r\n“Por que dices que tu amor es bueno \r\nPor que dices que tu amor es eterno \r\nPor que me ilucionastes \r\nY luego me traicionastes \r\nPor que me hicistes sufrir \r\nSi antes de conocerte yo era muy feliz \r\nPor que Cuando Te marchastes \r\nNo hice nada para impedirlo \r\nY cuando me ignorastes \r\nHice todo para resistirlo porque \r\n\r\n“TE AMO” \r\n\r\nPor estar contigo haria lo que fuera\r\nBajarte una estrella del cielo si pudiera \r\nLlevarte con migo hasta el fin del mundo \r\nPor estar contigo aunque sea un Segundo \r\nMi amor por ti es mas grande de lo que tu te inmaginarias \r\nY si buscas otro igual se que no lo encontrarias \r\nCuando estoy contigo siento que estoy volando\r\nY poquito a poco mis problemas se me van borrando \r\nPor robarte un beso de tu boca soy capaz de cualqier cosa \r\nSer agresivo o simplemente regalarte una rosa \r\nTu saves bien que “mi amor es “SINCERO” \r\nAsi que ven abrazame y Te dire TE QUIERO” \r\n","label_name":"","release":"","track_type":"original","key_signature":"","isrc":"","video_url":null,"bpm":null,"release_year":null,"release_month":null,"release_day":null,"original_format":"raw","license":"all-rights-reserved","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/32750851","user":{"id":8839325,"kind":"user","permalink":"yokire","username":"KIRE gc","last_modified":"2015/08/27 05:01:58 +0000","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/8839325","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/yokire","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000091460114-epzxq3-large.jpg"},"permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/yokire/lagrimas-del-corazon","artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000016446529-fei8hn-large.jpg","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/gQhrKNkPnPwd_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/32750851/stream","playback_count":14042,"download_count":100,"favoritings_count":1,"comment_count":0,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/32750851/attachments"}`